# Can't access class module collection with Key, "Run-time error 13 - Type mismatch"

Tags: excel, vba, class, collections, module

I have a class module setup to create a collection of the same class. My goal is to assign a Key based on the individual items' existing property. However, whenever I try to access an item in the class module collection based on this Key, I get "Run-time error 13 - Type mismatch".

Here is the stripped down code for the class module  :

```
Option Explicit


Private mstrKey                         As String
Private mblnChecked                     As Boolean

Private mtnpsColl                       As Collection



Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set mtnpsColl = New Collection
End Sub

Public Sub Add(Object As tnpObject)
    mtnpsColl.Add _
        Item:=Object, _
        Key:=Object.Key
End Sub

'Also tried this alternative with the same results
    'Public Sub Add(Object As tnpObject, Key As String)
    '    mtnpsColl.Add _
    '        Item:=Object, _
    '        Key:=Key'
    'End Sub



Public Function Item(Index As Integer) As tnpObject
    Set Item = mtnpsColl.Item(Index)
End Function

'Also tried declaring Item with Property Get
    'Found examples of both Item function and Property Get
    'Unclear what the difference is
    
    'Public Property Get Item(Index As Integer) As tnpObject
    '    Set Item = mtnpsColl.Item(Index)
    'End Property

Public Function Count() As Integer
    Count = mtnpsColl.Count
End Function



Public Property Let Key(Value As String)
    mstrKey = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Key() As String
    Key = mstrKey
End Property



Public Property Let Checked(Value As Boolean)
    mblnChecked = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Checked() As Boolean
    Checked = mblnChecked
End Property
```

...and here is the test sub to compare how a standard collection and this class module collection function:

```
Option Explicit


Public Sub TestClsModuleColl()
    
    'Standard collection, the "control group"
    Dim objColl                         As Collection
    
    'Class module collection
    Dim tnpsTest                        As tnpObject
    
    'A couple of items to add to these collections
    Dim tnpItem1                        As tnpObject
    Dim tnpItem2                        As tnpObject
    
    Dim i                               As Integer
    
    'Set and populate both collections with these simple items
    Set objColl = New Collection
    
    Set tnpsTest = New tnpObject
    
    Set tnpItem1 = New tnpObject
    Set tnpItem2 = New tnpObject
    With tnpItem1
        .Key = "something true"
        .Checked = True
    End With
    
    objColl.Add tnpItem1, tnpItem1.Key
    tnpsTest.Add tnpItem1
'Also tried this alternative with the same results
'    tnpsTest.Add tnpItem1, tnpItem1.Key
    
    With tnpItem2
        .Key = "something false"
        .Checked = False
    End With
    
    objColl.Add tnpItem2, tnpItem2.Key
    tnpsTest.Add tnpItem2
'Also tried this alternative with the same results
'    tnpsTest.Add tnpItem2, tnpItem2.Key
    
    'No problem accessing standard collection items based on Index
    With objColl
        For i = 1 To .Count
            Debug.Print .Item(i).Key
            Debug.Print .Item(i).Checked
        Next i
    End With
        
    'No problem accessing standard collection items based on Key
    Debug.Print objColl.Item("something true").Key
    Debug.Print objColl.Item("something true").Checked
    
    'No problem accessing class module collection items based on Index
    With tnpsTest
        For i = 1 To .Count
            Debug.Print .Item(i).Key
            Debug.Print .Item(i).Checked
        Next i
    
    'Error when accessing class module collection items based on Key
        'Run-time error 13, Type mismatch
        Debug.Print .Item("something true").Key
        Debug.Print .Item("something true").Checked
    End With
    
End Sub
```

I get the sense that the standard collection class has more functions/properties to access an Item based on the Key. However, I can only find examples on how to setup a collection within the class module as shown above. Is there more lines of code I need to add to the Item function? Does it matter if Item is decclared as a Function vs Property Get? Do I need to change the variable type away from integer? I'm in the dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter of your Item-function is an integer, therefore string is not a valid type.

If you want to access it either by index or by key your have to set the parameter to variant.